# VBO + Текстура =?

Tags: графика, c++, opengl

Как отрисовать Куб с разными текстурами на гранях, (1 грань -> 1 текстура) и как это реализовывать через  *VBO*?!

---

## Зачем всё это:

Весь сыр в том, что когда мы отрисовываем 1-100 кубов через `glBegin()`/`glEnd()`, это не столь критично и там это решается нескольким вложенными  `glBegin()`/`glEnd()` с "Биндом" текстур.
Но это очень затратно по времени (т.к. Рендерим МНОГО КУБОВ).

---

Моя реализовать выглядит так.

Если кто знает, как решить эту задачу по-другому, был бы рад посмотреть не его реализацию!

## Логика

1. Создать 6 граней куба.
2. Внести все грани в разные массивы.
3. "Биндить" текстуру.
4. Отрисовывать грань.
5. `if`(Количество проходов<6) `goto` 3.

## Код: C++

```
struct CFace
{
    GLint v1,v2,v3;
};
struct CVertex3
{
    GLfloat x,y,z;
};  
CFace f[10];
CVertex3 vQuad[8];
vQuad[0].x = 0.0f;      vQuad[1].x = 2.0f;      vQuad[2].x = 2.0f;
vQuad[0].y = 0.0f;      vQuad[1].y = 0.0f;      vQuad[2].y = 2.0f;
vQuad[0].z = 0.0f;      vQuad[1].z = 0.0f;      vQuad[2].z = 0.0f;>
vQuad[3].x = 0.0f;
vQuad[3].y = 2.0f;
vQuad[3].z = 0.0f;
vQuad[4].x = 0.0f;      vQuad[5].x = 2.0f;      vQuad[6].x = 2.0f;
vQuad[4].y = 0.0f;      vQuad[5].y = 0.0f;      vQuad[6].y = 2.0f;
vQuad[4].z = -2.0f;     vQuad[5].z = -2.0f;     vQuad[6].z = -2.0f;<
vQuad[7].x = 0.0f;
vQuad[7].y = 2.0f;
vQuad[7].z = -2.0f;
        /*!
                            /7--------/6
                           / |       / |
                          /  |      /  |
                         3---------2   |
                         |  /4- - -|- -5
        y                | /       |  /
        |/z              |/        | /
        0->x             0---------1/
        */
f[0].v1 = 0; f[0].v2 = 1; f[0].v3 = 2;      // 1 треугольник
f[1].v1 = 2; f[1].v2 = 3; f[1].v3 = 0;      // 2 треугольник
f[2].v1 = 4; f[2].v2 = 5; f[2].v3 = 6;      // 3 треугольник
f[3].v1 = 6; f[3].v2 = 7; f[3].v3 = 4;      // 4 треугольник
f[4].v1 = 0; f[4].v2 = 4; f[4].v3 = 3;      // 5 треугольник
f[5].v1 = 3; f[5].v2 = 7; f[5].v3 = 4;      // 6 треугольник
f[6].v1 = 1; f[6].v2 = 5; f[6].v3 = 2;      // 7 треугольник
f[7].v1 = 2; f[7].v2 = 6; f[7].v3 = 5;      // 8 треугольник
f[8].v1 = 3; f[8].v2 = 7; f[8].v3 = 6;      // 9 треугольник
f[9].v1 = 6; f[9].v2 = 2; f[9].v3 = 3;      // 10 треугольник
f[10].v1 = 0; f[10].v2 = 4; f[10].v3 = 5;   // 11 треугольник
f[11].v1 = 5; f[11].v2 = 1; f[11].v3 = 0;   // 12 треугольник

  //Далее отрисовываем по одной грани куба и "биндим" новую текстуру
for(GLint i(0);i<6;i++)
{
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[i]);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,sizeof(CVertex3),vQuad);// Указываем массив вершин.
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(CTexmap),tex);
        // Передаём массив индексов вершин.
        // Первый параметр - тип примитивов (у нас 2 треугольника), второй -
        // количество полигонов * количество вершин в примитиве. В нашем случае -
        // 2 полигона * 3 точки. У GL_QUADS было бы 2*4, и т.п.
        // Далее передаём тип переменной (GL_UNSIGNED_INT), и наконец массив индексов
        // вершин (полигонов.
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,36,GL_UNSIGNED_INT, Массив какой то грани[i]);   
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

Comment: Сюда загляните, может, поможет, там списки отображения используют для вывода фигур: http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/nehe12.htm

Comment: в одной из моих реализация я так и делал, производительность меня не устраивает

Comment: не знаю, будет ли прогресс, если текстуру составить из шести текстур для каждого полигона в одном файле и подгружать ее с соответствующими координатами, так поступают в игровых разработках, например, с фигурами с большим количеством полигонов (например, скин для персонажа).

Comment: отрисовывать грани несколькими glDraw**(), перед каждым из которых биндить нужную текстуру, либо как уже сказали(если текстура не слишком крупная) то все текстуры сгенерировать в одну

Comment: Так я описывал этот способ в своей реализации
~(отрисовывать грани несколькими glDraw**(), перед каждым из которых биндить нужную текстуру, либо как уже сказали(если текстура не слишком крупная) то все текстуры сгенерировать в одну)~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У Вас в коде используется не совсем VBO, а обычные массивы. При VBO координаты вершин предварительно загружаются в видеопамять.
2. Все 6 текстур можно объединить в одну текстуру. Это позволит забиндить текстуру один раз, а не шесть, и вывести куб одним VBO.